# Application failing based on browser version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in my Rails application. I recently started having a problem where if I called the app from Firefox, everything works fine, if I called it from my iPhone or from Chrome, it fails.

Here's the test server log file relevant information:

When I try using iPhone or Chrome:

```
Started GET "/" for xx.xxx.xxx.xx at 2013-06-18 18:20:58 +0000
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  BlogPost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `blog_posts`.* FROM `blog_posts` 
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (78.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_promo_bar.html.erb (65.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 539ms
```

When I use Firefox:

```
Started GET "/" for xx.xxx.xx.xx at 2013-06-18 18:21:43 +0000
  User Load (55.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  BlogPost Load (2.3ms)  SELECT `blog_posts`.* FROM `blog_posts` 
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (16.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (7.4ms)
  User Load (8.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
  User Load (6.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'mine@mydomain.com'
  Rendered layouts/_promo_bar.html.erb (14.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (8.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 566ms (Views: 362.7ms | ActiveRecord: 81.0ms)
```

So, it's failing as it processes layouts/_footer.html.erb. Note that this is the only file that uses Twitter Boostrap functionality. Following is layouts/_footer.html.erb

```
<% admin = nil %>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% roles = array_from_json(current_user.role) %>
    <% if roles.include?("admin") %>
        <% admin = TRUE %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer_column left_padding">
    <ul class="footer_column_list">
      <li class="footer_column_header"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Mission", about_path %>         </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Team", our_team_path %>            </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Advisory Board", advisors_path %>  </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="footer_column">
    <ul class="footer_column_list">
      <li class="footer_column_header"><%= link_to "Conference", event_path(Current_event_id.to_s) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Description", event_path(Current_event_id.to_s) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Speakers", speakers_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Schedule", schedule_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Travel Information", travel_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to REQUEST_INVITE_TITLE, new_user_registration_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <% if admin %>
      <div class="footer_column">
        <ul class="footer_column_list">
          <li class="dropdown" id="admin_menu">
            <a class="footer_column_header" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#admin_menu">
              <%= ADMIN_TITLE %>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% Admin_menu.each do |menu_text, menu_action| %>
                  <li><a href="<%= menu_action %>"><%= menu_text %></a></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% else %>
      <div class="footer_column">
        <ul class="footer_column_list">
          <li class="footer_column_header">Admin Functions</li>
          <li><%= link_to "Admin log-in", new_user_session_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="footer_column">
    <ul class="footer_column_list last_on_right">
      <li class="footer_column_header"><%= link_to "Blog", "http://ourblogg.com/" %></li>
      <li><%= image_tag('facebook-icon.png') %> <%= link_to "Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com/ourfbaccount" %></li>
      <li><%= image_tag('twitter-icon.png') %> <%= link_to "Twitter", "http://twitter.com/ourtwacct" %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Could this be a Twitter Bootstrap issue, and if so, any ideas how to fix it?

Additional note:

When I precompile assets on the test server:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.6
```

Comment: There isn't any backtrace for the error in the logs?

Comment: I cleared test.log prior to trying each browser, and what you see is the entire content of the test log fine. Does adding config.log_level = :debug to environments/test.rb convince it to include more info?